# Spacing of Chapter Name and Chapter Number when using package sectsty

Tags: color, chapters, koma-script, titlesec, sectsty

Hello my dear fellow latex users! I've been trying to fancy my thesis by setting a color to the chapter names and in order to do so, I used the package sectsty, because I am using a template where if I use titlesec everything gets terribly messed up.

The question is: How do I get to separate the chapter name and chapter number. As you can see, it is the only thing that gets messed up here.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{Verde}{RGB}{99,154,0}
\chapterfont{\color{Verde}}
\sectionfont{\color{Verde}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Mexican Hat}

Mi casa es tu casa

\section{La cucaracha}

Ya no puede caminar

\end{document}
```

Though I've been using Latex for a while now, I have never gone too deep to make my own renewcommands and stuff. So I'd love to keep using sectsty, because I wouldn't know how to improve all the template with titlesec.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for providing a minimal document with your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is changing the colour of chapters and sections titles, you can use `\addtokomafont`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Verde}{RGB}{99,154,0}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{Verde}}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{Verde}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Mexican Hat}

Mi casa es tu casa

\section{La cucaracha}

Ya no puede caminar

\end{document}{chapter}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I've deleted my answer. There are too many KOMA details to keep track of. :)  But you don't need two commands if all sectioning commands are to have the same colour. You could use `\addtokomafont{disposition}{...}` to do all at once.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Your answer made me discover the `disposition` key :o)

Comment: It's the most opaquely named key I've ever encountered. :) Worthy of some of the keys used in R packages (if you're familiar with R).

Comment: For me it's perfectly clear (I'm French), albeit I don't know R.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's very simple and worked perfectly :)